# Direct computation for Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Prove by direct computation

$(1)$ $K(x,t)=t^{-\frac n2}$ $e^{-\frac {|x|^2}{4t}}$ the heat equation for $t\gt0.$

$(2)$ For any $\alpha \gt0$,$G(x,t)=(1-4\alpha t)^{-\frac n2} e^{\frac {\alpha|x|^2}{1-4\alpha t}}$ satisfies the heat equation for $t\lt \frac 1{4\alpha}$.

I tried lot but i don't know where i messed up so please could u show me the computation.
I would be grateful.
thanks in advance...

Comment: Context please.

Comment: This is all given in the problem, i am sorry what kind of context, for an example?

Comment: For example, what is $K(x,t)$?

Comment: That is just function depends on x and t. Now we have to show it satisfies heat equation.

Comment: Heat equation is $K_t -\Delta K=0$

Comment: Did you get any idea?

Comment: Replace in the Heat Eqn. and see what happens...

Comment: i did but computation became mess, is there any nice trick to compute it?

Comment: @RonGordon by the way $x$ is $n$ dimentional vector so we have show it satisfies $n$ dimensional heat equation..

Comment: @RonGordon by the way $x$ is $n$ dimentional vector $K$ difined in $\Bbb R^n \times (0,\infty)$ is called fundamental solution of heat equation,  we have show it satisfies $n$ dimensional heat equation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|x|^2=x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2\,$ and $\,e^{\beta|x|^2}=e^{\beta x_1^2}\cdots e^{\beta x_n^2}$, the check reduces to the one-dimensional case $n=1$.

1. So, let $K(x,t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{t}}$. Then for $t>0$ we find
   $$
   K_t=-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{2t^{3/2}}+\frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{4t^{5/2}},\quad
   K_x=-\frac{xe^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{2t^{3/2}},\quad
   K_{xx}=-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{2t^{3/2}}+
   \frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{4t^{5/2}},
   $$
   whence follows $K_t=K_{xx}$.
2. Let $G(x,t)=\frac{e^{\frac{\alpha x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{\sqrt{1-4\alpha t}}$ with some 
   $\alpha>0$. Then for $\,t<\frac{1}{4\alpha}\,$ we find
   $$
   G_t=\frac{2\alpha e^{\frac{\alpha x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{(1-4\alpha t)^{3/2}}+
   \frac{4\alpha x^2e^{\frac{\alpha x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{(1-4\alpha t)^{5/2}},\quad
   G_x=\frac{2\alpha xe^{\frac{\alpha x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{(1-4\alpha t)^{3/2}},
   $$
   $$
   G_{xx}=\frac{2\alpha e^{\frac{x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{(1-4\alpha t)^{3/2}}+
   \frac{4\alpha x^2e^{\frac{\alpha x^2}{1-4\alpha t}}}{(1-4\alpha t)^{5/2}},
   $$
   whence follows $G_t=G_{xx}$. The latter solution represents a blowup example  in Cauchy problem for the linear heat equation
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   u_t=u_{xx}, \;\;x\in\mathbb{R},\;\;0<t<1/4,\\
   u|_{t=0}=e^{x^2},\;\;x\in\mathbb{R},
   \end{cases}
   $$
   that admits a classical blowup solution 
   $$
   u(x,t)=\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{1-4t}}}{\sqrt{1-4t}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R},\;\;0<t<1/4.
   $$
   For more details see [Example of linear parabolic PDE that blows up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663355/example-of-linear-parabolic-pde-that-blows-up/664632#664632)